# R to Python t.test function conversion

Tags: python, r, scipy, statistics

can someone help me transform this R t.test function to python?
r code:
`t.test(y, mu = 85, paired = FALSE, var.equal =TRUE, alternative = "greater)`

Comment: might be relevant https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_1samp.html

Comment: cant figure it out still

Answer (score 1):

You are testing a single sample `x` against a population mean `mu`, so the corresponding function from SciPy is [`scipy.stats.ttest_1samp`](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_1samp.html).  When a second sample `y` is not given to `t.test`, `var_equal` and `paired` are not relevant, so the only other parameter to deal with is `alternative`, and the SciPy function also takes an `alternative` parameter.  So the Python code is

```
    from scipy.stats import ttest_1samp

    result = ttest_1samp(y, mu, alternative='greater')
```

Note that `ttest_1samp` returns only the t statistic (`result.statistic`) and the p-value (`result.pvalue`).

For example, here is a calculation in R:

```
> x = c(3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9)
> result = t.test(x, mu=2, alternative='greater')
> result$statistic
      t 
1.49969 
> result$p.value
[1] 0.09699043
```

Here's the corresponding calculation in Python

```
In [14]: x = [3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9]

In [15]: result = ttest_1samp(x, 2, alternative='greater')

In [16]: result.statistic
Out[16]: 1.499690178660333

In [17]: result.pvalue
Out[17]: 0.0969904256712105
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find this blog useful: https://www.reneshbedre.com/blog/ttest.html

This is below an example of conversion with bioinfokit package but you can use the scipy one.

```
# Perform one sample t-test using bioinfokit,
# Doc: https://github.com/reneshbedre/bioinfokit

from bioinfokit.analys import stat
from bioinfokit.analys import get_data
df = get_data("t_one_samp").data #replace this with your data file
res = stat()
res.ttest(df=df, test_type=1, res='size', mu=5,evar=True)
print(res.summary)
```

Out put :

```
One Sample t-test 

------------------  --------
Sample size         50
Mean                 5.05128
t                    0.36789
Df                  49
P-value (one-tail)   0.35727
P-value (two-tail)   0.71454
Lower 95.0%          4.77116
Upper 95.0%          5.3314
------------------  --------
```